# z scores, highest percentile ranking, different distributions

Tags: distributions, standardization, quantiles

Let a value $x$ have a z-score of (say) $+0.10$.  With respect to which distribution(s) can $x$ have the highest percentile ranking: normal, positively skewed, or negatively skewed?

Comment: Can you add more detail? At present this is incomprehensible & cannot be answered.

Comment: this seems to be a self-study question and should be amrked as such. draw a picture of an example for the mentioned distributions, mark the mean (z=0) and try to locate the position of z=0.1. This should get you started on the right track.

Comment: Is this z-score based on sample or population quantities?